# Calculate discount price of net amount in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi guys i got stuck at very simple step i want to calculate Discounted price  as net amount in sql server. I used the following sql statement:

```
SELECT ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       QUANTITY,
       RATE=RATE*(Discount/100),
       AMOUNT,
       DATE,
       Discount 
       FROM ITEM_DETAILS 
       ORDER BY ITEM_MODEL
```

1.It works fine but it has a problem because there will be no discount on every product so when there is no discount price i contains null and then null multiply with `RATE` and makes 
it null.What would be safe way of calculating discounted price in a database.

2.The condition should be there that when the `Discount price is zero(0)` the rate will be same as it is but when there is a value in discount column for the given product it should calculate it.
I hope it should be clear to all.

Any help would be greatly praised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple CASE should do;

```
SELECT ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       QUANTITY,
       RATE=CASE WHEN Discount IS NULL OR Discount=0 
            THEN RATE
            ELSE RATE*(Discount/100) END,
       AMOUNT,
       DATE,
       Discount 
       FROM ITEM_DETAILS 
       ORDER BY ITEM_MODEL
```

The case will basically check if discount is null or zero, and in that case use RATE as is, otherwise do the normal calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `Case` with `Colaesce` will solve your issues if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
SELECT ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       QUANTITY,
       RATE=RATE*(case when coalesce(discount,0) = 0 then 1 else Discount/100 end),
       AMOUNT,
       DATE,
       Discount 
FROM ITEM_DETAILS 
ORDER BY ITEM_MODEL
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use the **CASE** condition as below:

```
CASE WHEN discount > 0 then 'Value1' ELSE '0' END
```

So the result will be as follow:

```
SELECT ITEM_MODEL,
       ITEM_NAME,
       ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
       QUANTITY,
       (CASE WHEN Discount > 0 THEN RATE*(Discount/100) ELSE 0 END) AS MyRate
       AMOUNT,
       DATE,
       Discount 
       FROM ITEM_DETAILS 
       ORDER BY ITEM_MODEL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function

```
SELECT ITEM_MODEL,
   ITEM_NAME,
   ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
   QUANTITY,
   RATE=RATE*(ISNULL(Discount, 100)/100),
   AMOUNT,
   DATE,
   Discount 
   FROM ITEM_DETAILS 
   ORDER BY ITEM_MODEL
```